# how to parse data from two csv in node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, npm, fs

I am very new to node.js. I have one script that will parse the csv and generate the required output file. Now I want to fetch some of column data from another csv at the same time and add that value to the output file.

Script :

```
var csv = require('csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var progress = require('progress-stream');
var date = require('date-and-time');

var indexStat = 0;
var header = [];

var headerLine = '$lang=en\n\nINSERT_UPDATE Customer;uid;name;address;phoneno'

var delimeter = ',';
var semicolon = ';';

var inputFile = __dirname+'/project/customer.csv';
var outputFile = __dirname+'/project/customer.impex';
var inputFileName = 'customer.csv';
var outputFileName = 'customer.impex';

function generateRecord(json) {

  var record = semicolon + json.uid + semicolon + json.name + semicolon + json.address;

  return record;
}

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile);

var parser = csv.parse({
delimiter: delimeter
}, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
});

var transformer = csv.transform(function (data) {
var line = '';
if (indexStat == 0) {
    header = data;
    var line = headerLine;
} else {
    var line = generateRecord(generateRecordObject(data));
}
indexStat++;
writeStream.write(line + '\r\n');
});

function stringSplitter(dataRow) {
  var str = dataRow.toString();
  return str.split(delimeter);
}

function generateRecordObject(dataRow) {
  var record = {};
  dataRow.forEach(function (value, index) {
    if (header[index] != '') {
        record[header[index].toLowerCase()] = value;
    }
});
return record;
}

var stat = fs.statSync(inputFile);
var str = progress({
  length: stat.size,
  time: 100
});

str.on('progress', function (progress) {
   writeCompletedPercentageForRead(progress.percentage, progress.eta, progress.runtime, progress.speed);
});

function removeLineBreaks(obj) {
  obj = obj.replace(/\\N/g, '');
  obj = obj.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
  return obj;
}

function writeCompletedPercentageForRead(p, e, r, s) {
  process.stdout.clearLine();
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
  process.stdout.write(`${inputFileName} read in progress to write ${outputFileName} ... Completed:${parseInt(p, 10)} %, ETA:${e} seconds, Elapsed:${r} seconds, Rate:${parseInt(s/1024, 10)} KBps`);
};

fs.createReadStream(inputFile).pipe(str).pipe(parser).pipe(transformer);
```

customer.csv ->

```
uid,name,address
1234,manish,bangalore
```

The above script is working fine and generating customer.impex file as below

```
INSERT_UPDATE Customer;uid;name;address;phoneno
;1234;manish;bangalore
```

Now i want to populate `phoneno` as well but phoneno field is define in another csv file lets say 'customer_phone.csv'.

customer_phone.csv -

```
uid,phoneno
1234,98777767467
```

I want to match uid column of customer.csv with customer_phone.csv and get the phoneno from that csv. Finally i want to add phoneno in the customer.impex outfile file.

I have no idea how to parse two csv here and generate the file. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var fs = require("fs");

var pathToMainCSV = "./customer.csv";
var pathToContactsCSV = "./contact.csv";

var customerConverter = new Converter({});
var contactConverter = new Converter({});

var contanierObj = {};

function processContacts() {
    fs.createReadStream(pathToContactsCSV).pipe(contactConverter);
}

function createImpexFile() {
    var headerLine = '$lang=en\n\nINSERT_UPDATE Customer;uid;name;address;phoneno;\n';
    Object.keys(contanierObj).forEach(obj => {
        Object.keys(contanierObj[obj]).forEach(data => {
            headerLine += contanierObj[obj][data] + ';';
        });
        headerLine += '\n';
    });
    fs.writeFile("./new.impex", headerLine, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
}

customerConverter.on("end_parsed", function(jsonArray) {
    jsonArray.forEach(v => {
        contanierObj[v.uid] = v;
    });
    processContacts();
});

contactConverter.on("end_parsed", function(jsonArray) {
    jsonArray.forEach(v => {
        contanierObj[v.uid].contact = v.phoneno;
    });
    createImpexFile();
});

fs.createReadStream(pathToMainCSV).pipe(customerConverter);
```

Kindly use something like i have done above, format the string according to your needs